# How to split String from one word to another?

Tags: java, android

For example I have `String info = "You have 2$ on your public transport card and one active ticket which expires on 2017-08-09 23.59"` and I want to get only two parts of it `"2$"` and `"one active ticket which expires on 2017-08-09 23.59"`.

I tried to do this with `split()`, but I cant find how to split from one word to another on the internet. Also I cant change `String info`, because I'm getting it from external server.

Comment: Don't use `split()` for this. Use `Pattern` to apply a **regex** pattern, and *capture groups* in the pattern to extract the values you need. If you don't know regex yet, not would be a great time for you to learn. Here is an example of a regex: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QyUSpJ/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work.

```
String info = "You have 2$ on your public transport card and one active ticket which expires on 2017-08-09 23.59";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\$).*and\\s(.*)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(info);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("First Group: " + m.group(1) + " \nSecond Group: " + m.group(2));
    }
```

Just like Andreas said before, you should use Pattern and regular expressions to find the groups in your String info and then you can safe them in variables, for now i just printed them.